# How do I add specific data from the original monthly average dataset to a new dataset?

Tags: r, filter, average

I have an input data set with average monthly water flow for a river. This file has monthly data from 1912 to 2021 and I have read it into the program as "input1". I am trying to create a new dataset called "AugAvgs" that only includes the average August water flow for the years 1980 through 2021. I am new to programming in R and am not sure how to go about this.

Here is my current failed attempt:

```
AugAvgs$year <- as.numeric(c(1980:2021)) #creates august table and fills year column

AuAvgs$avg <- input1$mean_va(year>1980, month=8)
```

The line of code that creates AugAvgs and fills in the year column works. The next line of code attempting to add the specific data is giving me the error "Error: attempt to apply non-function". I believe this is because "input1$mean_va" is in the function location, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried using a series of if statements to filter through the data, but that did not work either because I was using an array with if statements that required single variables. How should I go about doing this? Thank you for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `mean_va` is a column in `input1`. You can subset to years greater 1980 and month == 8. To only include august means after 1980.

```
input1[input1$year > 1980 & input1$month==8,]$mean_va
```

It would really be helpful to include a sample output of `input1` and not a screenshot. Upon looking at the screenshot with the supposed column names you might try this. This assumes the columns are integers.

```
input1[input1$year_nu > 1980 & input1$month_nu==8,]$mean_va
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you!